# Using Nutch to fetch particular HTML Tags

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, nutch

I will be little verbose to clearly specify the problem, so please be patient :)

Assume I have the following base URL: http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/all-deals?ie=UTF8&type=bd
which lists a number of products with a concise description. Each listed product has a URL directing to a details product information page like: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000WU7RGS/ref=xs_gb_all-deals_center_rw_uk_A34K0C99MV3O0U?pf_rd_p=1261804642&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=30&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1FE5R5X5XYMG6GDPHPK5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000WU7RGS)

Now my requirements is to (for example) fetch name, price and product information for each of these products. How can I achieve this using Nutch? Is Nutch required/good option for this or just a plain simple wget + own HTML parser is a better way to go?

Note: I have to do this for multiple pages with very different layout and only input will be the URL and what html tags to fetch from the URL

Answer (score 0):

Working on the same problem. However, it seems like there are some tiring steps to achieve the goal:

1-crawl 2-index 3-get the raw html by -readseg 4-parse the file for information you want

So, **Nutch** doesn't seem to be the good way to do this. Have you managed to find out an answer?